# Why doesn't git rebase -i :/^major work?

Tags: git

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.6

$ git rebase -i :/^major
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream :/^major
```

Reading gitrevisions(7) and googling, I still can't figure this out. I understand for some reason :^/major returns the whole revision range (tested with git log), instead of only commits where messages start with major. Let's assume in this case I actually do have only one commit message starting with "major". This to me is not clear from documentation. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
git rebase -i $(git rev-parse :/^major)
```

It looks like the command *should* work, but `git rebase` doesn't parse the revision that way. Smells like a bug/unintended feature to me.

Comment: Very nice, this works. I wonder if this is improved in >1.7.6.